# Multiple images in card views with Glide only shows the last loaded items

Tags: android, firebase, imageview, picasso, android-glide

I am using Glide (also made a try with Picasso with the same behavior) to load a list of image urls into cards that should be shown in a camera view. Everything is working like a charm, but if i try to load more then around 8-12 images, only some of the last created cardviews are shown. Views created before are completely removed or shown as squashed image without card layout. There are no loading errors or further informations in the console log.

Now comes the crux of the story. When i exclude the images from the cardviews or use a local drawable as the image content, even loaded with Glide, all cards are displayed as expected.

I thought about a caching issue and added `android:largeHeap="true"` with no success. Also i've used a small thumbnail for all cards. Same scenario.

This is the function i am using to create the cardview's from a list of pois:

```
       for (PlacesModel placesModel : mPlacesModelList) {

           if ((placesModel.getDistance() / 1000f) < showDist) {

              View view = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.ar_view, null);
              view.setTag(placesModel.getPlaceId());
              view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              ImageView img = view.findViewById(R.id.card_view_image);

              view.setScaleY(setSize(placesModel.getDistance()) / 8.0f);
              view.setScaleX(setSize(placesModel.getDistance()) / 8.0f);

              TextView text = view.findViewById(R.id.t);
              TextView desc = view.findViewById(R.id.d);

              text.setMinWidth(200);
              text.setText(placesModel.getPlaceName());

              desc.setText(Config.cDist(placesModel.getDistance()));

              text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, setSize(placesModel.getDistance()) / 3.0f);
              desc.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (setSize(placesModel.getDistance()) - 1) / 2.0f);

              Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                      .load(placesModel.getImageThumbnail())
                      .thumbnail(0.1f)
                      .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                      .error(R.drawable.no_image)
                      .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                         @Override
                         public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                         }
                         @Override
                         public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                         }
                      })
                      .into(img);

              infl.addView(view);
              }
           }
        }
```

This is the according layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/marker"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:onClick="cardViewClicked"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/mainMarker"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
    app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/card_view_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxWidth="80dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.FontPath.Bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/d"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxWidth="80dp"
            android:text=""/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mainMarker"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_marker" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create CardView and its contents dynamically (programmatically). In XML file, just create a layout and add the cards using CardView dynamically inside java file.

Create object inside class, but outside onCreate method.

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout;
```

Then, link the layout using its id

```
relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.marker);
```

Then create a function which will be called while creating a card. Code inside that function will look like:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("Something...");
CardView cardView = new CardView(this);
cardView.addView(textView);
relativeLayout.addView(cardView);
```

Comment: Thanks. I am already using this. Everything is working without images. All elements are shown. The problem only occours when images are loaded into the existing cardviews.

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: Thanks Qwais. I've found the solution. The problem was how Glide is setting the layout parameters to the parent container.

Comment: That's great then.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.

There was a Glide info in Logcat where others mentioned i can be slightly ignored.

```
Glide treats LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT as a request for an image the size of this device's screen dimensions. If you want to load the original image and are ok with the corresponding memory cost and OOMs (depending on the input size), use override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL). Otherwise, use LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, set layout_width and layout_height to fixed dimension, or use .override() with fixed dimensions.
```

Now i had only to set the layout parameters to `Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL` like this

```
view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                      Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL,
                      Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL));
```